# All other input data get clear when I remove an input

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi i am working on a React application where there are four inputs.when a user add an input the element will be added to the wrapper.In the following code add operation works fine but remove operation is not working properly ,it is not removing the corresponding element.Another problem the values on the inputs fields not present when the component re-renders.so experts guide me how i can achieve removing the corresponding row when the remove button is clicked and the input values should not be reset when the component re-renders

So when I refresh the page and click to remove an input it will clear all other input data. How can I fix this problem ?

Update added full component to question:

```
const Agreement = (props) => {
  const { agreement, editable, teamData, teamId, fetchTeamData } = props;
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [showErrors, setShowErrors] = useState(false);
  const [errorsArr, setErrorsArr] = useState();

  const initialFormState = {
    rule_0: teamData.rule_0,
    rule_1: teamData.rule_1,
    rule_2: teamData.rule_2,
    rule_3: teamData.rule_3,
    creator: teamData.User.public_user_id,
  };

  const [updateTeamData, setUpdateTeamData] = useState(initialFormState);

  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(teamData.rules);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // Update state
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  // Add more input
  const addInputs = () => {
    setInputs([...inputs, { name: `rule-${inputs.length + 1}` }]);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputs];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputs(list);
  };

  const clearInput = (dataName) => {
    setUpdateTeamData((prevState) => {
      delete prevState[dataName];
      return {
        ...prevState,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setEditing(false);
    // Send update request

    console.log(updateTeamData);

    const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/teams/team/${teamId}`, updateTeamData);

    // If no validation errors were found
    // Validation errors don't throw errors, it returns an array to display.
    if (res.data.validationErrors === undefined) {
      // Clear any errors
      setErrorsArr([]);
      // Hide the errors component
      setShowErrors(false);
      // Call update profiles on parent
      fetchTeamData();
    } else {
      // Set errors
      setErrorsArr(res.data.validationErrors.errors);
      // Show the errors component
      setShowErrors(true);
    }
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setEditing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (agreement === "default") {
      setTitle(defaultTitle);
      setInputs(teamData.rules);
    } else {
      setTitle(agreement.title ?? "");
    }
  }, [agreement, teamData]);

  return (
    <div className="team-agreement-container">
      {!editing && (
        <>
          <h4 className="team-agreement-rules-title">{title}</h4>
          {editable && (
            <div className="team-agreement-rules">
              <EditOutlined
                className="team-agreement-rules-edit-icon"
                onClick={() => setEditing(true)}
              />
            </div>
          )}
          <p className="team-agreement-rules-description">{description}</p>
          {teamData.rules.map((rule, index) => (
            <div className="team-agreement-rule-item" key={`rule-${index}`}>
              {rule ? (
                <div>
                  <h4 className="team-agreement-rule-item-title">
                    {`Rule #${index + 1}`}
                  </h4>
                  <p className="team-agreement-rule-item-description">
                    - {rule}
                  </p>
                </div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
      {/* Edit rules form */}
      {editing && (
        <div className="team-agreement-form">
          {showErrors && <ModalErrorHandler errorsArr={errorsArr} />}
          <h1>Rules</h1>
          {inputs.map((data, idx) => {
            return (
              <div className="agreement-form-grid" key={`${data}-${idx}`}>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="agreement-remove-button"
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleRemoveClick(idx);
                    clearInput(`rule_${idx}`);
                  }}
                >
                  <Remove />
                </button>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder={`Rule ${idx + 1}`}
                  defaultValue={teamData.rules[idx]}
                  name={`rule_${idx}`}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
          {inputs.length < 4 && (
            <div className="team-agreement-add-rule">
              <button type="submit" onClick={addInputs}>
                <Add />
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="div-button">
            <button className="save-button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              Save
            </button>
            <button className="cancel-button" onClick={handleCancel}>
              Cancel
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Agreement;
```

Comment: Can you share your full component code? It's difficult to determine what else is at play.

Comment: Yes, one moment I’ll stare all my component

Comment: I see defaultValue is used for the input. I was wondering whether a value prop for the input is missing? Is uncontrolled components the desired approach?

Comment: Just added full the component into my question. May you take a look?

Comment: @DeanJames I think it probably because my defaultValue

Comment: Can anyone help me with this?